# Evaluating this integral $ \int_1^\infty \frac{2|\log x|K_1(2|\log x|)}{x^3}~dx \approx 0.33333 \approx 1/3 $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have an integral and I think it evaluates to a rational number, specifically $1/3,$ but I am not completely sure. Here is the integral:

$K_1$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind:

$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{2|\log x|K_1(2|\log x|)}{x^3}~dx \approx 0.33333 \approx 1/3 $$

I have done some numerical testing with Desmos and Wolfram alpha and they agree with each other to about the 5th decimal place.

> Is there an analytic approach to validate that the integral is indeed equal to $1/3?$ Alternatively I'd accept an answer that numerically gives the decimal representation of $1/3$ truncated to the 20th decimal place.

Comment: You can ignore the absolute value function, then make the substitution $u := \log x$ and see where that gets you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [Basset's integral representation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E11) of the modified Bessel function of the second kind shows that the integral has the same value as the integral $$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(t^{2}+1)^{5/2}}  \, \mathrm dt.$$

As **A rural reader** pointed out in the comments, the absolute values are not necessary since $\log (x)$ is nonnegative on $[1, \infty)$.

$$\begin{align} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2 \log(x) K_{1}(2 \log x)}{x^{3}} \, \mathrm dx &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} u K_{1}(u) e^{-u} \, \mathrm du  \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} ue^{-u} \, \frac{2 \,  \Gamma \left( \frac{3}{2}  \right)}{\pi^{1/2} \,  u} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ut)}{(t^{2}+1)^{3/2}} \, \mathrm dt \, \mathrm du \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(t^{2}+1)^{3/2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u} \cos(tu) \, \mathrm du \, \mathrm dt \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(t^{2}+1)^{5/2}} \mathrm dt\\ &= \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{v^{-1/2}}{(v+1)^{5/2}} \, \mathrm dv \\ &\overset{(1)}{=} \frac{1}{4} \, B\left(\frac{1}{2}, 2 \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{4}{3} \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{3}. \end{align}$$

---

$(1)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas

Comment: +1 this is a nice answer @Random

Comment: Agreed, very nice.

Comment: @user577215664 Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For  the most general case of
$$I=\int_1^\infty \frac {a\log(x)\,K_1(a\log(x))}{x^n}\,dx$$ you can obtain nice results involving $\pi$.
$$x=e^{\frac t a} \quad \implies \quad I=\frac 1a \int_0^\infty t \, e^{\frac{(1-n) }{a}t}\,K_1(t)\, dt$$
$$I=\frac {(n-1)}{(n-1)^2-a^2}+\frac{a^2 \left(\pi-2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{n-1}{a}\right)
   \right)}{2 \,\left(a^2-(n-1)^2\right)^{3/2}}$$ which looks to be undefined for $n=1+a$ as in your case, but in fact:

$$\int_1^\infty \frac {a\log(x)\,K_1(a\log(x))}{x^{a+1}}\,dx=\frac{2}{3 a}$$